# Something feels not right with my proof for $X_n \to X$ a.s. and $Y_n \to Y$ a.s. then $X_n + Y_n \to X + Y$ a.s.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification

I am trying to prove: if $X_n \to X$ a.s. and $Y_n \to Y$ a.s. then $X_n + Y_n \to X + Y$ a.s. I saw the proofs here in stackexchange and I understand them so far but I am curious about my "proof". It feels like I missed something important or did a stupid mistake but I can't figure out where (or maybe its right? :D). Thank you so far guys! Here the proof:

Let there be an $\varepsilon$ such that $\frac{\varepsilon}{2} > \vert X_n -X \vert$ and $\frac{\varepsilon}{2} > \vert Y_n -Y \vert$ for some sufficient big $n = n(\varepsilon) \in\mathbb{N}$. This $\varepsilon$ exist due to the a.s. convergence of our assumptions further it holds:

$\varepsilon > \vert X_n -X \vert + \vert Y_n -Y \vert \geq \vert (X_n +Y_n) - (X +Y) \vert$

Further:

$0 \leq P (\{ \vert (X_n +Y_n) - (X +Y) \vert \geq \varepsilon\}) \leq P (\{ \vert X_n -X \vert + \vert Y_n -Y \vert \geq \varepsilon \}) \leq P (\{ \vert X_n -X \vert \geq \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \}   \cup \{\vert Y_n -Y \vert \geq \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \}) \leq P (\{ \vert X_n -X \vert \geq \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \}) +P( \{\vert Y_n -Y \vert \geq \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \})$

And this equals $0$ due to the assumptions and it follows  $X_n + Y_n \to X + Y$ a.s. (where the last step comes from $P(\limsup \limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \{ \vert X_n -X \vert > \varepsilon) = 0 $ which is equivalent to a.s.).

I don't think the proof is totally right and I miss something. Especially on the last step. I am not sure that I can say that this also holds for the $\limsup \limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}$ case but I also don't find an argument why not. Maybe you guys can help me out.

Comment: You can find $n$ such that $\vert X_n-X\vert<\varepsilon/2$, but this $n$ depends on $\omega$. So you cannot say that $\mathbb P(\vert X_n-X\vert<\varepsilon/2)$ is 0 because nothing tells you there exists such an interger $n$ for which the property $\vert X_n-X\vert<\varepsilon/2$ holds for any $\omega$.

Comment: Moreover, you must take into account that this convergence only holds a.e., hence not for every $\omega.$

Comment: Thank you guys! Now I have two questions left :D:
1. It depends on $\omega$ because of the pointwise convergence and that its just converge a.e. right? 
2. And my last step in generel where I conclude this for the $\limsup \limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}$ is in generel ok/right or not?